# discord.js@12.5.3 add role command

Tags: discord, discord.js, roles

I'm trying to make a add role and remove role command, I've tried before and given up since I could never get my head around it. I want the command to allow someone to mention a user then mention a role and give/take that role to/from the user. The command doesn't give the role and it seems like content.replace doesnt work either. Here is my code for the give role command:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: "addrole",
    description: "Give a role to a user",
    aliases: ["+role", "giverole", "give-role"],
    cooldown: 3,
    permissions: "MANAGE_ROLES",
    execute(msg, args){
        const Discord = require('discord.js');
        require("discord-reply")
        const { colour } = require('../config.json')
        const { version } = require('../config.json')
        const { prefix } = require('../config.json')

        let user = msg.mentions.users.first() || msg.author
                                                              //v  e.g  $ addrole @user test role  = test role
        let r1 = msg.content.replace(`${prefix} ${args[2]} ${user} `, ``)//removes everything before role name
                      //^ content.replace doesn't seem to work
        let role = msg.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === r1);

        if (!r1) {   //checks for anything after the user
            msg.channel.send("You need to give a role name")
        } else if (!role) {
            msg.channel.send("That role doesn't exist")
        } else return


        user.roles.add(role).catch(console.error);
    
        console.log(`Made it this far`)
    }
}
```

Comment: And what was your issue with the code, which part didn't work properly? Could you please include it in your question?

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the question to include my issue, the command simply won't work.

Answer (score 0):

In my modest experience I think your `args[2]` does not exist because, according to your snippet, you should've already created a `messageCreate` event and defined command. So try using:

```
let r1 = msg.content.replace(`${prefix}role ${user}`, ``) 
// Or ${prefix}addrole/+role ${user}
let role = msg.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === r1);
```